# Vue.js: can't update the Data Store variables with a get request made via Axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using Vue.js.
Here, it's about a component.
I've got a variable named "comments" in my Data Store.
I want to update it via the "created" section of the script (so further I can update my html element via a v-for loop in "comments").
I do use Axios to send the request.

Problem: right after the Axios GET request I see that I have the correct response, and I can  assign "res.data" to "this.comments". As you'll see on the picture I can see the result in the console, when I iterate through "this.comments", and console.log() the result: I see the correct result. (As you can see on the picture: lines 26, 28, 30)

Outside of this loop, the log in the console precise: Proxy.(line: 32)

*But the variable "comments" in the DataStore is **NOT** updated.* I can't iterate through "comments" as it is still 'undefined'...

Last log of the console (see the snapshot below) ;

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at eval (CommBox.vue?6cb4:6)
```

I've read that it may be because of the arrow functions used in the get request and the use of "this" ?

If this is Right, (that it's because of the arrow functions), how I should re-write this code, so it does update the variable "comments" in the Datastore ?

PS: the thing that I don't understand is that I have another .vue file, used as a View, and the same kind of code (code that is below) does Work... Maybe for this compoment it is also because I want a dynamically updated component in an dynamically updated view ?

the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        
        <div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" > 
            <p> {{ comments[comment].id }} </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import "../main.css";

export default {
    name: "CommBox",
    data() {
        return {
            comments: undefined,
        }
    },
    created() {
        let MessageId = localStorage.getItem('MessageId');
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/comments/" + MessageId,  { headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")} })
        .then(res => {   
            console.log(res.data)
            for (let i in res.data) {
                console.log(res.data[i].id)
                this.comments = res.data;
                console.log(this.comments[i].id)
            }  
            this.comments = res.data;
            console.log(this.comments)
     
        })
        .catch((error) => {console.log(error)
        });
        
    }
}
</script>
```

[image: the logs in the console]

Comment: how your comment looks like? is it an object?  `comments[comment].id` seems to be incorrect

Comment: I've set the variable "comments" to undefined. It is supposed to be an array of objects in the end. As you can see, when I do the iteration "this.comments[i].id " I do the see the correct answer in the console, but I can't update the variable in the datastore, the same loop in "this.comments" with an iterator called comment, does not work, as this.comments remains "undefined".

Comment: i think the problem is that you are trying to render comments before the data is loaded, try to add `v-if="comments"` to the `div`

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `comments` with `[]` because a component template expects it would an array and because `axios.get` is an asynchronous operation and the `created` hook does not wait for it to complete so a component is rendered **before** `comments` is filled with results of `axios.get`.

```
data() {
        return {
            comments: [],
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
    <div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" > 
        <p> {{ comments[comment].id }} </p>
    </div>
```

In your case, `comment` is an object in the `comments` array, not the `index`. So the `comments[comment]` is `undefined`, that's why it says `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. Try this:

```
    <div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" > 
        <p> {{ comment.id }} </p>
    </div>
```